# cleartool: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or priveleged user. cleartool: Error: Trouble loading versioned object base

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Performed fix_prot on a VOB database dump from Linux into Windows. Fix_prot said the re-protection was complete. So, I tried to run a cleartool reformatvob - load and receive the following: cleartool: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or priveleged user.
           cleartool: Error: Trouble loading versioned object base .

Don't understand why it's still not letting me load the VOB.

Answer (score 1):

It is one limitation of the [`cleartool reformatvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_reformatvob.htm) command:

> You must have one of the following identities:
>
> - VOB owner
> - root (UNIX and Linux)
> - Member of the ClearCase administrators group (ClearCase on Windows)

I usually perform a load as root (on Linux), or, in your case on Windows, as a member of the ClearCase admin group.
Then I do a [`cleartool protectvob`](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm) to change the vob ownership.

In that order, it works.